# Override catalina properties in embedded tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I would like to override catalina property "shared.loader" in embedded tomcat (version 9). I am launching the embedded tomcat using plain java class.

Please provide any suggestions. If I am setting as JVM property, it is not working. I am using embedded tomcat in Spring MVC application (just as an fyi, not springboot).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The _common_, _shared_ and _server_ classloaders are used only in the usual Tomcat (they are configured by the `Bootstrap` class). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have multiple war files which has shared dependencies. I would like to point the catalina property shared.loader to the shared dependencies (which i will place in a folder).

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't created your own class loader hierarchy, just add `/path/to/shared/folder/*.jar` to the class path of your application and the shared classes should be visible to any embedded web application.

If you have created any sort of class loader hierarchy, add the shared folder to the class path of whichever class loader loads the embedded Tomcat JARs.

Comment: classpaht solution works for me. That was my current scenario. I am trying to make changes related to class loader hierarchy. This is where changes are not working. I will live with classpath solution for now. Thanks.